# How to set the data from server into this dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [this](http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/xaAXG) bootsnipp for BootStrap.JS to create dynamic fields and capture data from the form.

After save, lets say I get back data as JSON from server as key value pairs, how I can construct this dynamic form so the user can update it again.

Any sample snippet would be helpful.

Comment: So you want to populate a form by using the JSON response meaning the form is always the same but the data changes? Or you want to use the data to build the form, meaning the data controls the form?

Comment: I supposed, it is a 2 step operation. The form contains the dynamic component as in the bootsnipp along with few other fields. User will be able to add as many dynamic fields as possible and submit the form. There is a method in the bootsnipp that collects the data from those dynamic fields. And now the missing part - when the saved data is returned from the server as a json response, when i load the page, the dynamic fields should be rendered based on the response from server.

Comment: hi take a look at this fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/65QB3/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to write some data propagating method, rather easy, here's a quickie (Data from server are stored in variable `requestData`, also I removed unnecessary code):

```
var requestData = [{"name":"phone0", "value":"890890809"},{"name":"fax1", "value":"1111"},{"name":"skype2", "value":"anonononono"},{"name":"email3", "value":"huhuhuhu@huhuhu.pl"}];

function capitalize(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

(function ($) {
    $(function () {

        var addFormGroup = function (event) {
            [...]
        };

        var removeFormGroup = function (event) {
            [...]
        };

        var selectFormGroup = function (event) {
            [...]
        }

        var countFormGroup = function ($form) {
            [...]
        };

        var collectData = function(ele) {
            [...]
        }

        var propagateData = function(data){
            var $formGroup = $('body').find('.form-group');

            $.each(data, function(k,v){
                var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();
                $formGroupClone.find('.btn-add').toggleClass('btn-success btn-add btn-danger btn-remove').html('–');
                $formGroupClone.find('input').val(v.value);
                $formGroupClone.find('.concept').text(capitalize(v.name.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')));
                $formGroupClone.find('.input-group-select-val').val(v.name.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''));
                $formGroupClone.insertBefore($formGroup);
            });

        }

        $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', addFormGroup);
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', removeFormGroup);
        $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', selectFormGroup);
        propagateData(requestData);
        $('#data').click(function(e){
            collectData('.cache');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

## EDIT

well, all the code to reset the form is hidden inside propagate data, you just have to reverse it, in your html you should add something like this `<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning form-reset" style="margin: 10px;">Reset</a>` and then the complete js is here:

```
var requestData = [{"name":"phone0", "value":"890890809"},{"name":"fax1", "value":"1111"},{"name":"skype2", "value":"anonononono"},{"name":"email3", "value":"huhuhuhu@huhuhu.pl"}];

function capitalize(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}


(function ($) {
    $(function () {

        var addFormGroup = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
            var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');
            var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();

            $(this)
                .toggleClass('btn-success btn-add btn-danger btn-remove')
                .html('–');

            $formGroupClone.find('input').val('');
            $formGroupClone.find('.concept').text('Phone');
            $formGroupClone.insertAfter($formGroup);

            var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
            if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') <= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
                $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        };

        var removeFormGroup = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
            var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');

            var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
            if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') >= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
                $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', false);
            }

            $formGroup.remove();
        };

        var selectFormGroup = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var $selectGroup = $(this).closest('.input-group-select');
            var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
            var concept = $(this).text();

            $selectGroup.find('.concept').text(concept);
            $selectGroup.find('.input-group-select-val').val(param);

        }

        var countFormGroup = function ($form) {
            return $form.find('.form-group').length;
        };
/* collectData Function~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/ 
This function given a group of elements (in classic selector format) will assign each element 
the values of the closest fields as a unique name and the user entered value (if any.)
Use the console to see it gather data.
*/
        var collectData = function(ele) {
            var $tgt = $(ele);
            $tgt.each(function(index) {
// $tgt == $(this)
                var $fieldNames = $(this).next('.input-group-select-val').val();
                var $fieldValues = $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.form-control').val();
// Including index to each $fieldName in order to make each key/value pair unique.
                $(this).attr('name', $fieldNames+index);
                console.log('name: '+$(this).attr('name'));
                $(this).val($fieldValues);
                console.log('value: '+$(this).val());
              });
        }

        var propagateData = function(data){
            var $formGroup = $('body').find('.form-group');

            $.each(data, function(k,v){
                var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();
                $formGroupClone.find('.btn-add').toggleClass('btn-success btn-add btn-danger btn-remove').html('–');
                $formGroupClone.find('input').val(v.value);
                $formGroupClone.find('.concept').text(capitalize(v.name.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')));
                $formGroupClone.find('.input-group-select-val').val(v.name.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''));
                $formGroupClone.insertBefore($formGroup);
            });
        }

        var clearData = function(elms){
            $(elms).not(':last').remove();
            var $el = $(elms);
            $el.find('input').val('');
            $el.find('.concept').text('Phone');
            $el.find('.input-group-select-val').val('phone');
        }

        $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', addFormGroup);
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', removeFormGroup);
        $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', selectFormGroup);
        propagateData(requestData);
// Clicking the #data button will call the collectData('.cache') function.
        $('#data').click(function(e){
            collectData('.cache');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('.form-reset').click(function(e){
            clearData('.multiple-form-group');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Awesome that worked for me. Can I also ask how can I reset the form, lets say on click of a reset button, I want to default to single entry and remove the rest and clear the values?

Comment: @JAGAMOT see updated answer, all you have to do is to reverse the logic of adding data

Comment: I know the question is answered. What can I do to get two sets of these dynamic fields on the same page which can be under two different forms?

Comment: You should wrap it in unique classes and abstract the code to take them as a parameter